# How to connect to an iphone through Java? Is this even possible?

Tags: iphone

I am trying to write a program in Java that can connect to an iPhone that is attached to a computer via apple USB cable and view its files. I have not found anything like this online and have been wondering if this is even possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

iOS is problematic because of DRM. Android is also moving in that direction making standard file system browsing difficult so I doubt it would be possible to view arbitrary files on the device.

[Codename One](https://www.codenameone.com/) allows you to build a Java app that will run on the iPhone itself which might allow you to access some data. However, apps running in the device also have restrictions and can't access the full file system only their own.